# handleOpenURL won't trigger iOS Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, instagram-api

I am trying to get an Instagram authentication token for an app Im working on, I have the app opening safari, Im able to log in and then it send me back to the app, but when it transfers me back to the app, handleOpenURL is not triggering in AppDelegate. Here is a sample of my code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

....
    func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        InstagramAPIManager.sharedInstance.processOAuthStep1Response(url)
        print(url)
        print("handleOpenURL")
        return true
    }

}
```

and here is a my API Manager code that is triggering safari to open:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class InstagramAPIManager {
    static let sharedInstance = InstagramAPIManager()

    func startOAuth2Login() {
        let clientID: String = "abcdefg"
        let authPath:String = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=\(clientID)&redirect_uri=grokInstagram://?aParam=paramVal&response_type=code"
        if let authURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: authPath)
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(authURL)
        }
    }
....

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You do know that `handleOpenURL:` is deprecated, right? In iOS 9 you should be using `func application(_ app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool`

Comment: I did not know that, thank you!

Comment: Worked great, thanks so much!

Comment: I'll give it as an answer, then. Glad it worked!

Comment: Any idea on how I would get an OAuth2 token from the Instagram app if installed on the device? Oh also, you had "option" written twice, and the _ threw an error, but Xcode fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS 9, `application:handleOpenURL:` is deprecated. Instead, you should be using:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, 
    openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax seems to be

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                          open url: URL,
                          options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

according to https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application